# Way to send a 1080p 60Hz ʜᴅᴍɪ signal over a floor with the same loss level as a 6 meter cable?

Tags: hdmi

The task sounds simple the aim is to send an ʜᴅᴍɪ signal from computer to large ᴛᴠ where the 2 can’t fit in the same room at the same time…

There’s 7 meters air gap between the 2 devices… and a concrete floor.

## What I searched

I heard a 60Ghz radio solution can’t be used in this situation because it can be almost stopped by a paper sheet.

I heard that the bandwidth of 5Ghz device would allow transmitting the signal so I bought an ʜᴘ Wireless ʜᴅᴍɪ transmitter operating on that band : and the compression is so high that the quality is definitely better on 640×480×16 ᴄʀᴛ.
**Maybe a 5Ghz transmitter on that band would be able to transmit the video in a way which can be considered lossless and that I just didn’t found the right device.**

Then one would argue to just use a wired solution. However with the distance to reach the stair and hallway what is 7 meter radio gap becomes a 35 meters wire. Of course, with such a long wire the quality is just as bad as with wireless.

How to solve this ? As the ᴛᴠ runs on Webos and supports 802.11 Wi‑Fi with 270Mb/s real speed (which would be enough to send the video signal over X11 but with the problem the program I want to use require Vulkan or Direct3D12) a software solution would be OK.
There’s definitely must be a way : with ᴅᴠʙ‑ᴛ I can record 14 channels all at 1080p30Hz at the same time (with a single Tuner) with almost no compression and a frequency well below 1Gz.

Comment: Looks like I need a Home tv channel broadcaster with a range which don’t exceed 20 meters. Seems that solution need to be created.

Comment: @cybernard no ethernet is availaible. Also it s not possible to use cpl because the electric smart counter use an incompatible technology. Why using ethernet when regular Wi Fi is in therory fast enough? In fact the tv works already very fine with DLNA, if I could install a virtual screen which would send the video s signal using that protocol (the problem here is what I want to send isn t a static video so I can t just convert to a file).

Comment: @cybernard that’swhat I said : Ethernet. I’m not find leaving any cable running in the stairs. Everything is connected through radio here.

Comment: Could you tell us what you are trying to stream from the PC to the TV? There may be a solution specific to your use-case other than trying to stream the HDMI signal. Are you willing to consider additional hardware like an Android HTPC?

Comment: @Romen gaming… but Bluetooth control isn’t a problem. The game is fully compatible with android and supports the same control (through again bluetooth) but there’s just one catch : the graphic hardware which would be powerful enough to play at the planned antialiasing and resolution and framerate is likely to require mobile hardware of the end of the next decade (as no x86 laptop can be made fast enough for the current scenario so ᴀʀᴍ is far worst). Otherwise, the framerate is measurable in minutes instead of seconds.

Comment: @Romen however ᴄᴘᴜ isn’t a problem and it should be possible to emulate it on android from ᴘᴄ. This wouldn’t be the first time I use game designed to playable at full quality with hardware not existing yet. In therms of size, the ᴛᴠ and the ᴘᴄ can’t lie in the same room.

Comment: I brought up Android because you can use software on your desktop PC specifically meant for streaming games (Steam Remote Play, Nvidia Gametream) and receive the stream on an Android device plugged in to the TV. It forwards any bluetooth or USB controller too. The quality of the video compression is good compared to what you might get from an HDMI transmitter.

Answer (score 1):

Streaming the HDMI signal itself is a very tricky thing to achieve since 1080p HDMI signals are uncompressed and 1080p60hz requires about 3 Gbit/s. That is a very high bandwidth to achieve wirelessly and I'm not surprised that the wireless HDMI kit you purchased was very poor quality. Even a 5Ghz Wireless AC router needs *4 antennas* with a MIMO system to reach that kind of bandwidth.

> ... (which would be enough to send the video signal over X11 but with the problem the program I want to use require Vulkan or Direct3D12) a software solution would be OK.

You have the right idea using a remote desktop solution.
In fact, there are a few solutions that exist specifically for streaming games:

- [Steam Remote Play](https://store.steampowered.com/streaming/)
- [Nvidia GameStream](https://support-shield.nvidia.com/gamestream-user-guide/#t=NVIDIA_GameStream.htm)

There are some decent remote desktop apps that can also grab full-screen content, such as NoMachine or Splashtop but they are less ideal compared to the gaming-first techs above. Windows' own RDP will work with windowed mode DirectX games too.

Out of all of those choices, I would try Steam Remote Play first. It uses the GPU's built in video encoding capabilities if supported, and falls back to the various graphics APIs available for copying the frame buffer and encoding on the CPU.

I asked if you would consider an Android HTPC in the comments above because they are cheap HDMI computers that support the client for Steam Remote Play. With a good GPU in the desktop the encoding/compression would be significantly higher quality than what you would get from a wireless HDMI adapter and the solution is still wireless.

Comment: With dvb-t you have 1080p25Hz with very high quality compression for 2mb/s raw stream or 30Mb/s of real bandwith. Something which should definitely possible over 5Gb/s Wi-fi. The problem is the YTv doesn t runs Android but WebOs which severaly limits compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

I know you were more interested in a wireless solution, but if you decide to go the wired route you can use an HDMI over Ethernet Extender. With the [Cable Matters Extender](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00OZV04BK), you can achieve 1080p @ 60hz with a max range of 300ft. There are other manufactures (such as IOGear) that make the same type of device, including 4K versions.

[image: https://www.amazon.com/Cable-Matters-HDMI-Extender-Ethernet/dp/B00OZV04BK]

Comment: Yep. no running cable for me. And please, I have no idea about feet size in my region.